# Nested For Loop - Calender

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.print("M   T   W   T   F   S   S");

            System.out.println();

            for (int d=1; d<=7; d++){
                System.out.print(d + "   ");
            }

            System.out.println();

                for (int e=8; e<=15; e++){
                    System.out.print(e + "  ");
                }

                System.out.println();

                    for (int f=16; f<=22; f++){
                        System.out.print(f + "  ");
                    }

                    System.out.println();

                        for (int g=23; g<=29; g++){
                            System.out.print(g + "  ");
            }
    }
```

Hi,

I am new to Java and was studying nested loops, i found a way to code a simple calender but i do feel like the code is redundant, is there a way to make this code more efficient or anything else that i should study to make it better?

Thank you.

output -

M   T   W   T   F   S   S

1   2   3   4   5   6   7
8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20  21  22
23  24  25  26  27  28  29

Comment: If you have working code that you want to improve, you might want to check if your question could be [on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If you're only looking for review, I believe [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is much better for this job.

Comment: To begin with, your second loop is incorrect (it prints 8 numbers rather than 7)

Comment: Then you've got two strategies : an outer loop that iterates from 0 to 3 (an iteration for each of your current loops) and generate the bounds of your current loops, which if I'm not mistaken are init=x*7+1 ; final=(x+1)*7, or a single loop that tests if it has just printed a printed a multiple of 7 days and adds a linefeed when that's the case

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like this:

```
for (int d=1; d<=29; d++){
    System.out.print(d + "   ");
    if(d % 7 == 0)
    {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

or, if you don't like that you can do this:

```
for (int d=0; d<4; d++){
    for (int i=1+d*7; i<=(d+1)*7; i++){
        System.out.print(i + "   ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Hope, I helped.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to nested for loops.

Try the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("M   T   W   T   F   S   S");
    for(int i=1; i < 30; i++){
        if (i % 7 == 0){
            System.out.println(i + "   ");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(i + "   ");
        }
    }
}
```

Definitely consider using `\t` instead of a bunch of spaces. This will display the output with better clarity. However, if you wish you have these spaces, keep this as is.

Comment: Thank you so much, as i am new to Java and was learning nested loops, i was trying to solve the problem with loops itself and not using any other methods as a matter of fact i learnt that i can use if-else inside the for loop, i was trying to solve it with just for loops. appreciate the help.

Comment: @SD23 No worries! Glad I could help! Consider marking this answer as correct if you found it helpful. It helps other users easily find answers to similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check `String format` to get the output cleaner.

But, to do easier I'll use `\t`.

You have to think what's your code do: Iterate over the days in a month. So you only need one loop from 1 to 30.

And, when to do a break line? When the month is completed. That is -assuming monday start with 1- when the day can be dividied by 7.

So the loop you need is something like this:

```java
System.out.println("M\tT\tW\tT\tF\tS\tS");
//Iterate over every day in the month
for(int i = 1; i <= 30; i++){
    System.out.print(i+"\t");
    if(i%7 == 0){
        //If the day is the last in the week
        //we go to the next week
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And the oputput is:

```
M       T       W       T       F       S       S
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       
8       9       10      11      12      13      14      
15      16      17      18      19      20      21      
22      23      24      25      26      27      28      
29      30
```

It's not a good idea create multiple loops when you can do all in one.

If your first loop is from 1 to 7 and the second one from 8 to 15... why not use only one from 1 to 15?